# Identity server 4 AspNet Identity Missing method

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an angular 2 page with a service that tries to authenticate on a Identity Server 4 via token endpoint.

I'm trying to use Identity Server 4 with Entity Framework Core for Clients and Scopes and AspNet Identity for the users

but i'm getting a strange Missing method exception

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable`2<!!0,!!2> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable`2<!!0,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<!!1>>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!1,!!2>>)'.
```

This happens after getting the clients and scopes validated

I can't understand what the error is... If you need any code just ask

Comment: Did you upgrade to 1.0.0-rc4? I did yesterday and just started getting this error this morning.

Comment: I reported the issue on GitHub as well: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/issues/40

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using .NET Core 1.1. IdentityServer 4 does not yet support .NET Core 1.1 due to introduced bugs/breaking changes in the security libraries.

See https://twitter.com/leastprivilege/status/801723059149357056 for full discussion.

### Edit

IdentityServer 4 now supports .NET Core 1.1 and csproj.

Comment: Then how do i downgrade? what do i need to do?